# How to Publish Robot Test Results from multiple nodes in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, robotframework

I am executing robot tests parallelly on multiple jenkins' node.
And at the end I want to publish robot result separately for all those node. How to do this?
I tried with the "rebot" option to combine the result but i don't want this approach.

Comment: In the execution you can set the output file(s) names, just set different names for each block and in the end you can create different reports or simply publish them.

Comment: yes but in the console, i will only see the publish report for the last node generated. And what about report.html? should it be different?

Comment: Each execution will generate 3 files: report.html, output.xml and log.html
If you want to have separate reports you need to name each file on the execution. Nevertheless, the robot plugin for jenkins only reads 1 report, if you want that plugin to have 3 reports, make 3 different jobs with the different script executions.